# How can I handle a regression question about time series by tsfresh package (python)?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

How can I handle a regression question about time series by tsfresh package (python)?

Recently, I need to forecast the volume of sales. I find a great Python package **tsfresh** 
http://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html

The example in quick start is a solution about classification. I want to know how to use it to solve regression problem. I want to extract the features from time series data. But when I use the method **extract_features**, I get same the feature for a series of data and I can't figure out what time these features belong to. It has been bothering me for a long time.

[My training data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haowp.png)

Comment: Hey there, I do not get your question. Just use the feature matrix from extract_features to build a regression mode with sklearn, with e.g. random forest regressor or another method.